# Chess clock non-functional in ongoing game

Tags: rules, fide, chess-clocks

I would like to know what happens to a game, according to FIDE rules, in the case of a clock becomeing non-functional during ongoing game.

Is the chess game abandoned and declared a draw match? Is the clock replaced by another clock, and iis the game resumed from there? Finally, has this incident happened in an World Chess Championship matches to date?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens should a clock fail during the game?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/28304/what-happens-should-a-clock-fail-during-the-game)

Comment: Thanks. So is this a draw or the game is continued with another clock?

Comment: @RewanDemontay It also needs more focus. several questions are asked. Edit out all the duplicate questions and it would likely be acceptable. Scatter-bombing the forum with duplicates because you just can't be bothered to search first is antisocial as well as against the rules.